# How to apply CSS on first span only?

Tags: html, css

This is my html section where I want to apply CSS for `class="richC"` for first span only. I don't want to apply the CSS on span of span tag

```
<span class="richC">
    <span id="3">
        <span style="border-top: 1px solid black;"> √23 </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Here is the CSS which I have applied I even tried to use `:first child`

```
.richC span {
   background-color: #d6edfd;
   border-radius: 10px;
   display: block;
   margin: 10px;
   color: #1776bb;
   font-weight: normal;
   padding: 2px 10px;
   border: 2px solid #1776bb;
}
```

Comment: I am happy to give you a help. would you accept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want? If not, explain your idea more specifically.

```
span.richC > span { background-color: #d6edfd;
       border-radius: 10px;
       display: block;
       margin: 10px;
       color: #1776bb;
       font-weight: normal;
       padding: 2px 10px;
       border: 2px solid #1776bb;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to add for the first child only? Then go for `first-child` pseudo element.

```css
.richC span:first-child {
  background-color: #d6edfd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #1776bb;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  border: 2px solid #1776bb;
}
```

```html
<span class="richC">
  <span id="3">
    <span style="border-top: 1px solid black;"> √23 </span>
    <span style="border-top: 1px solid black;"> √234 </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need booth ">" and ":first-child"

```css
.richC > span:first-child {
  background-color: #d6edfd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #1776bb;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  border: 2px solid #1776bb;
}
```

```html
<span class="richC">
  <span id="3">
    <span style="border-top: 1px solid black;"> √23 </span>
  </span>
</span>
```